# How to Scrape Cache Share Post Facebook on React js from Website?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, facebook

I am trying to share a video from my website with og tags for Title, Description and Image. Which works at first try but if you Update one of those on the website, Facebook Doesn't Update the Cache and keeps the old informations if you try to share it again.

This is for a platform to edit videos online. Made out of ReactJs, A-Frame, Firebase, MongoDB. You can edit the Name and Description of the project anytime and share it. But as I said, when you do, Facebook doesn't update the cache. And as it suppose to be use by professional, I'd like to find out a solution where the User doesn't need to go trough the Facebook Debug platform..

```
getView(uid) {
    return Promise.all([
      repository.findOneOrFail({ slug: uid }),
      JSDOM.fromFile(path.join(__dirname, 'video.view.html')),
    ])
      .then(([video, dom]) => {
        try {
          dom.window.document.body.innerHTML = video.content;
          if (video.title) {
            dom.window.document.title = video.title;
          }
          domHelper.populateMetas(dom.window.document, {
            'og:title': video.title,
            'og:description': video.description,
            'og:image': video.projectThumbnailSrc,
            'og:url': `${process.env.BASE_URL}video/${video.slug}`,
          });

          return dom.serialize();
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        throw { status: 404, message: 'Not found', error };
      });
},
```

```
    <meta property="og:type" content="video.movie" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="" />
    <meta
      property="og:description"
      content="A Web experience."
    />
    <meta property="og:image" content="" />
```

While I expect the updated informations to show, as said earlier, I don't have any error message or anything but it just simply doesn't display the New informations and keep the Old ones.

Does anyone know if it is possible? Or I have no other choice than pass by the Facebook Debug Tool??

Thanks already to all whom gonna answer..

Comment: You can use the API to tell Facebook to scrape the URL https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/getting-started/change-link